# Convert strings to nested XML data

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have the following strings:

```
"Sweden, Västmanland, Västerås" 
"Sweden, Dalarna, Leksand" 
"Ireland, Cork, Cobh"
"Ireland, Clare, Boston"
"Ireland, Cork, Baltimore"
"Sweden, Dalarna, Mora"
```

which I wish to convert to xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<data>
<country name = "Ireland">
    <region name = "Clare">
        <settlement name  = "Boston"/>
    </region>
    <region name = "Cork">
        <settlement name = "Baltimore"/>
        <settlement name = "Cobh"/>
    </region>
</country>

<country name = "Sweden">
    <region name = "Dalarna">
        <settlement name = "Leksand"/>
        <settlement name = "Mora"/>
    </region>
    <region name = "Västmanland">
        <settlement name = "Västerås"/>
    </region>
</country>
</data>
```

What built in libraries for python3 might help me to do this conversion so that I needlessly reinvent the wheel?

Comment: That is not valid XML markup. You need to use attributes or XML text, a bare `=` without attribute name is not valid.

Comment: This is otherwise a somewhat non-constructive question (you are basically asking for suggestions for libraries and approaches). Have you tried anything yourself yet? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: "Sorting" doesn't apply to XML. Unless you mean grouped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

strings = ["Sweden, Västmanland, Västerås",
"Sweden, Dalarna, Leksand",
"Ireland, Cork, Cobh",
"Ireland, Clare, Boston",
"Ireland, Cork, Baltimore",
"Sweden, Dalarna, Mora"]

dd = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for s in strings:
    a, b, c = s.split(', ')
    dd[a][b].append(c)

root = ET.Element('data')

for c, regions in dd.items():
    country = ET.SubElement(root,  'country', {'name': c})
    for r, settlements in regions.items():
        region = ET.SubElement(country, 'region', {'name': r})
        for s in settlements:
            settlement = ET.SubElement(region, 'settlement', {'name': s})


import xml.dom.minidom # just to pretty print for this example
print(xml.dom.minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root)).toprettyxml())
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<data>
    <country name="Ireland">
        <region name="Cork">
            <settlement name="Cobh"/>
            <settlement name="Baltimore"/>
        </region>
        <region name="Clare">
            <settlement name="Boston"/>
        </region>
    </country>
    <country name="Sweden">
        <region name="Dalarna">
            <settlement name="Leksand"/>
            <settlement name="Mora"/>
        </region>
        <region name="Västmanland">
            <settlement name="Västerås"/>
        </region>
    </country>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your input into dictionary as follows:

```
strings = ["Sweden, Vastmanland, Vasteras",
"Sweden, Dalarna, Leksand", 
"Ireland, Cork, Cobh",
"Ireland, Clare, Boston",
"Ireland, Cork, Baltimore",
"Sweden, Dalarna, Mora" ]

d = {}
for s in strings:
    tmp = s.split(", ")
    country = tmp[0].strip()
    region = tmp[1].strip()
    settlement = tmp[2].strip()

    if d.get(country):
        if d[country].get(region):
            d[country][region].append(settlement)
        else:
            d[country][region] = [settlement]
    else:
        d[country] = {region: [settlement]} 

for k, v in d.items():
    print k,v
```

This gives the following output:

```
Sweden {'Vastmanland': ['Vasteras'], 'Dalarna': ['Leksand', 'Mora']}
Ireland {'Clare': ['Boston'], 'Cork': ['Cobh', 'Baltimore']}
```

Now you can easily convert this dict to xml string.

Although, jamylak's answer is way better.